# Provide status of an Activity based on date column in a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

In the view have to provide `Status` based on date.

The condition is:

- If one of the activities doesn't have a date for the person, then `Status` is `Active`
- If all the activities have a date for the person, then `Status` is `Not Active`

How do I get `STATUS` for a person?

For example:

```
|PersonId|Name|Activity | Date      | 
+--------+----+---------+-----------+
| 1      |John| a       | 01/01/2015|
| 1      |John| b       | 03/12/2016|
| 1      |John| c       | 02/13/2017|
| 2      |Sam | d       | 06/01/2014|
| 2      |Sam | e       | 05/18/2016|
| 2      |Sam | f       | NULL      |
```

Output in the view:

```
|PersonId|Name|Status    | 
+--------+----+----------+
| 1      |John|Not Active| 
| 2      |Sam | Active   |
```

Comment: @Marc_s Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select personid, name,
       (case when count(*) = count(date) then 'Not Active' else 'Active' end) as status
from t
group by personid, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Gordon's answer is better, but since I started typing this out, I figured i'd finish it anyway.
something like

```
declare @maxDate date = datefromparts(9999, 12, 31)

select case when max(isnull(Date, @MaxDate)) = @maxDate) then 'Active' else 'inactive'
from ...
```